# Showing a graph of website activity, to check whether it is stagnant or active

Tags: alexa

I thought [Alexa](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/knol.google.com) had a kind of graph to show how a website's activity was progressing over a period of time. I wanted to see how [Knol](http://knol.google.com/) had evolved this year, but I am having trouble finding this on a graph.

I can't even find an Alexa page dedicated to knol.google.com to see it track such activity.

How much a site is stagnant/active is subjective, but even though it is not perfect, at least some metrics could be used: incoming links, traffic, content updates, and how often the website's name appears in discussions.

Is there something else perhaps that tracks this?

Comment: Edited it in a way that gives you both options, how to see it in Alexa, and offers of other web apps that can do this instead

Comment: OK, why not. Google Trends is also somehow close to what I am looking for: http://www.google.com/trends?q=knol but unfortunately a single metric does not make for a very reliable activity measure. And for instance "backlog.jp" is not findable on Google Trends.

Comment: Old news, but [Knol is dead](http://knol.google.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Isn't Google Analytics the best web application for such purposes? I mean they provide you with all the stats like incoming links, traffic, pageviews etc...?

Comment: Google Analytics is really nice indeed. Too bad I can't see the stats of websites I do not own. I should have precised I want to see stats of sites that I don't own, like knol.google.com and others.

Comment: hmm... now i get the problem. will keep an open eye for such service.